# extract URL from another cell to be used in importrange function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to optimize some spreadsheets I use at work and I have an idea that would save me a good bit of time.  I have a formula which extracts a bunch of data from another spreadsheet and organizes it.

What I would like is to have the spreadsheet hyperlinked in cell A2 and then have a formula in B2 which uses importrange while extracting the url from the hyperlinked text in A2. Is this possible?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1syq5Hx-VglAiiYy185h5Nz7HzuBVZngBqfKpl0z527k/edit#gid=0

I would like for the formula in B2 to use the url in cell A2 if possible.

Answer (score 1):

if A1 is hyperlink / formula try:

```
=IMPORTRANGE(REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(SPLIT(FORMULATEXT(A1), " "),,1), """(.*)"""), 
 "Sheet1!A1")
```

[image]

---

if A1 is not hyperlinked there were **[scripts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/125907/186471)** for this but none of them works nowadays

but there is an add-on that can convert non-hyperlinks into hyperlinks:

**https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/extract_urls/143780651832**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick response player0. I added a sample spreadsheet as a reply to your comment on the original question.