# Edit Multiple Links at Once In Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working with some very large spreadsheets. There is clickable text that has an embedded link in many of the cells. However, I want to edit the cells so that they contain the actual links rather than the text.

I know how to do this manually (click below link to see image), one entry at a time, but need to figure out how to do all of them in one go.

[google sheets - "edit link"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nL5s.png)

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66045594/5632629

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this function to the Apps Script ended up solving it for me.

```
function GetURL(input) {
  var myFormula = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  var myAddress = myFormula.replace('=GetURL(','').replace(')','');
  var myRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(myAddress);
  return myRange.getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl()
 }
```

Source:
[oksheets.com/extract-hyperlink-url/](https://www.oksheets.com/extract-hyperlink-url/#:%7E:text=By%20hovering%20your%20mouse%20across,into%20any%20cell%20you%20wish.)